# Handle very large distance matrix in C (or C++ if it could help)

Tags: c++, c, cluster-analysis, large-data

I am implementing this clustering algorithm http://www.sciencemag.org/content/344/6191/1492.full ([free access version](http://sites.psu.edu/mcnl/files/2017/03/9-2dhti48.pdf)) in C in my software and I need to build a distance matrix, but in some cases, the size of the dataset (after redundancy removal) is huge (n > 1 500 000 and it is even larger, going up to 4 000 000 on more complex cases). My problem is, even allocating the upper triangular matrix would be `( (1500000*1500000) - 1500000) * 0.5 * sizeof(float) =~ 5.5e12 Bytes`. So, memory allocation fails (even on our computing nodes with 256 GB of RAM) and writing to disk is not an option in this case.

Beside cutting down the size (which I will look) of the dataset to cluster, anybody has an idea of a technique I could use to approximate and store this amount of information ?

N.B. Like I said in the title, I am using C and I can also use C++. Also, if anybody has another clustering algorithm (where the number of clusters is determined with the algorithm itself) to use, please suggest it to me.

Thanks in advance for your time,

Comment: is it a sparse matrix? If so, there could be a chance ... otherwise, use another algorithm which does not rely on stored values.

Comment: Your link requires a log-in.

Comment: @davidhigh the redundancy removal (if working as intented) should not let any 0 value in the upper triangular matrix. As of now, I have ~0.25% of values at 0. So, no, it isn't sparse.

Comment: The link is barely relevant. The algorithm implementation and details are [available for free](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/344/6191/1492/suppl/DC1), they just take the distance matrix the OP is referring to as input.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, sorry the link to the paper isn't open access, but Xīcò gave a better one. The paper is not that relevant to solve my problem.

Comment: Don't forget about DBSCAN, OPTICS etc. - they work well, and are widely accepted as good algorithms. The Science article got rather critical reception by domain experts (and Science is not a domain journal either...)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I looked at DBSCAN and it looks like it requires `O(n^2)` memory. As for OPTICS, I will look further into it, I don't know much about this algorithm. In all cases, I think I will need to do as Michael suggested in his answer.

Comment: No, it does not. I needs `O(n)` memory, and with index `O(n log n)` runtime. Same for OPTICS. The problem is a lot of papers (including that dubious Science paper you are using) don't have their facts right. DBSCAN is also not "iterative"; k-means is iterative.

Comment: (Note how the authors of the Science article avoid comparing to mean-shift more closely? And the Olivetti results are not particularly good, actually - they worked for one face; and some of the almost identical images are not in the same cluster?!? My guess is the paper was rejected somewhere because of being too similar to meanshift, so they tried Science next and pseudo-compare to meanshift in the introduction...)

Answer (score 8):

You probably have to step back and reconsider your algorithm.

First, perhaps you don't need to have distance matrix between all pairs of data points. Perhaps you could group together similar data points into data bins and then create a matrix of distances between bins.

That is, start by computing pairwise distances between points, but keep only relatively small distances and pointers to "the other" point. Kind of a very sparse matrix of shorter distances. This is straightforward to do in parallel.

Then create data bins that contain groups of points with mutually small distances between them. For example, if you threshold "short" distances in such manner that bins would hold on average, say, 50 data points you'd get 1500000/50=30000 bins.

Then go through your data again and compute distances between bins. That would produce 30000^2 distances, which is a matrix of about 4GB. In addition you still have 30000 with 50^2 distances within bins, which is another 300MB. This amount of data is quite manageable.

If replacing the distance between data points with a distance between the corresponding bins is sufficient precision for your application that would work. It all depends on the kind of data you are dealing with and the precision requirements of your application.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say "plus one" or "minus one" anymore, but I'll say it. Just the very first sentence is good enough for a "plus one" for this answer.